# Swift optional binding in generic function

Tags: swift, binding, functor, option-type, applicative

Lovely buggy swift amazed me once again.
In my new project I used optional applicative functor with `<*>` operator, described [here](http://www.objc.io/snippets/7.html).

```swift
infix operator <*> { associativity left precedence 150 }
func <*><A, B>(lhs: (A -> B)?, rhs: A?) -> B? {
    if let lhs1 = lhs {
        if let rhs1 = rhs {
            return lhs1(rhs1)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

And it was really cool, till I caught a weird crash. I'll show it in a simplified version.

```swift
let constant: AnyObject? = nil
func someFnc(obj: AnyObject!) {
    println("lol, wat?")
}
someFnc <*> constant
```

So, what will be the output? Of cause nothing, what would you expect? 
What if we pass a variable?

```swift
var variable: AnyObject? = nil
someFnc <*> variable
```

Same for this one you tell me, but my console says:

```swift
lol, wat?
```

Yep, thats right, if we pass var, it happily pass through optional binding check.
I tried this for `NSObject` and some Swift structs/classes, if I pass constant everything works fine, if it is a variable, some magic is going on.

**update**

Describing the magic going on, the `var` inside `<*>` function becomes nested `Optional` and `let` do not.

Is there any sensible explanation for this implicit behaviour?

**workaround**

For workaround you can wrap your variable in some function like:

```swift
var variable: AnyObject? = nil
func getVar() -> AnyObject? {
    return variable
}
someFnc <*> getVar()
```

Or in a computed property:

```swift
var variable: AnyObject? = nil
var getVariable: AnyObject? {
    return variable
}
someFnc <*> getVariable
```

Comment: I tried a bit of the above. The `someFnc <*> constant` (not videoInput) returns nil and `someFnc <*> variable` returns {(0 elements)} which is strange enough already. My best guess: drop it and wait for half a year :-/

Answer (score 4):

Here is what happens:

```
infix operator <*> { associativity left precedence 150 }

func <*> <A, B>(wrappedFunction: (A -> B)?, optional: A?) -> B? {
    println(optional)
    if let f = wrappedFunction {
        if let value = optional {
            return f(value)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func someFnc(obj: AnyObject!) {
    println("lol, wat?")
}

let constant: AnyObject? = nil
let result1: ()? = someFnc <*> constant
var variable: AnyObject? = nil
let result2: ()? = someFnc <*> variable
```

The result is:

```
nil
Optional(nil)
lol, wat?
```

So, our `var variable: AnyObject?` becomes a nested optional `AnyObject??` once it enters the `<*>` function. Its value is then Optional(nil), which is not nil, so the wrapped function is called on it. Yet another workaround could be to flatten the nested optional:

```
let result2: ()? = someFnc <*> variable?
```

But we don't need a workaround here. It's not a bug, there is a subtle error in the code. The problem is that `someFnc` has wrong signature. You use `AnyObject!`, which is implicitly unwrapped optional, so the signature of the function is `AnyObject! -> ()`. But the `<*>` operator requires `(A -> B)?`, not `(A! -> B)?`. Just change `func someFnc(obj: AnyObject!)` to `func someFnc(obj: AnyObject)` and it will work. I'm not really sure why the problem appeared only while using variable, and not with the constant.

That said, I don't think that the applicative operator should be used with variables and for side effects, as in this case. Also, avoid implicitly unwrapped optionals as much as possible. We saw how nasty they are. They allowed us to use wrong function without any warning.

**EDIT:**

I did few tests and there is definitely some weirdness going on:

```
func upperCase1(string: String?) -> String {
    println("calling upperCase1...")
    return string?.uppercaseString ?? ""
}

func upperCase2(string: String?) -> String? {
    println("calling upperCase2...")
    return string?.uppercaseString
}

func upperCase3(string: String) -> String? {
    println("calling upperCase3...")
    return string.uppercaseString
}

func upperCase4(string: String) -> String {
    println("calling upperCase4...")
    return string.uppercaseString
}

let constant: String? = nil
var variable: String? = nil

let mappedConstant1 = map(constant, upperCase1) // nil
let mappedVariable1 = map(variable, upperCase1) // Some("")

let mappedConstant2 = map(constant, upperCase2) // nil
let mappedVariable2 = map(variable, upperCase2) // Some(nil)

let mappedConstant3 = map(constant, upperCase3) // nil
let mappedVariable3 = map(variable, upperCase3) // nil

let mappedConstant4 = map(constant, upperCase4) // nil
let mappedVariable4 = map(variable, upperCase4) // nil
```

If we use `map` method instead of the global function, everything is `nil` in all the cases and none of the `upperCase[N]` functions is called. There is no difference in behaviour between regular and implicitly unwrapped optionals. The fact that variables and constants behave differently is not the worst thing here. The worst thing is that the compiler allows us to call `upperCase1` and `upperCase2`. The only two functions that should be allowed in this case are `upperCase3` and `upperCase4`, and the good news is that those two functions work correctly with variables.

Comment: Main concern of this mess is why `var` becomes a nested `Optional` and `let` don't. This implicit behaviour is really frustrating. I caught it once before, when I was playing around with RAC 3.0, and somehow got `Optional(Optional(something))` with some `Signal`. 

And I'd love to avoid implicitly unwrapped optionals as much as possible, but almost all ObjC SDK is wrapped in `swift` using them, so I don't have a big choice, but writing my own wrappers may be.

Well, thanks for your answer and especially for your workaround `someFnc <*> variable?`.

Comment: I've just reported this as a bug.

Comment: Just found that adding one more functor implementation — `<*><A, B>(lhs: (A! -> B)?, rhs: A?) -> B? { /* the same */ }` — makes the example code use _this_ new implementation and work fine with `var`s. As it's hard to avoid implicitly unwrapped optionals in Objective C API, perhaps this workaround would be safer than remembering to add `?` to every variable argument.

Comment: That's definitely cleaner for now and I think that it is exactly what compiler should do automatically, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be simplified as:

```
func foo<A>(v: A?, f:(A) -> Void) {
    println(v)
}

let constant: Int? = nil
var variable: Int? = nil
func someFunc(x: Int!) {}

foo(constant, someFunc)
foo(variable, someFunc)
```

output:

```
nil
Optional(nil)
```

So, with my assumption:

- `foo(constant, someFunc)` is interpreted as
  `foo(constant as Int?, someFunc as (Int) -> Void)`
- `foo(variable, someFunc)` is interpreted as
  `foo(variable as Int!?, someFunc as (Int!) -> Void)`

There is some ambiguousness here:

```
// `(Int!) -> Void` can be cast to `(Int) -> Void`
func f(Int!) {}
let f2 = f as (Int) -> ()

// `Int?` can be cast to `Int!?`
let i:Int? = 1
let i2 = i as Int!?
```

In this case, I think

- constant is stronger than parameter.
- parameter is stronger than variable.

I'm not sure this can be considered as a bug. It's very confusing at least.